# HIVE array<string>

Tags: sql, arrays, hive, null, hiveql

I need to get the empty array as NULL in my result set:

```
 select id,name,
 case when type = [] then NULL 
 else type 
 end as type
from table
```

Here type is defined as `array<string>`
I am getting error for the above.

Comment: try `type = array()`?

Comment: @mck nope didnt work , getting error

Comment: could you post the error message by [edit]ing your question?

Answer (score 1):

Check  `size(type) = 0`

```
   select t.id, t.name, 
          case when size(t.type) = 0 then NULL 
               else t.type 
           end as type
    from mytable t
```